# what is valid value for user object's tracking_codes attribute?

Tags: box-api

I was working on box user object and would like to know what is valid value for "tracking_codes" attribute. In Box develp doc, all examples for this attribute are empty json array. I tried with several possible values, such as [{"key_1" : "value_1"}, {"key_2" : "value_2"}], and ["key_1/value_1", "key_2/value_2"], and all got "invalid input" complain back from Box server. I googled it and could not find any useful info.

could you please give me some examples for this attribute's value?

many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The tracking_codes have to be enabled on the enterprise in order to be set.  Once enabled, they should accept any name-value pair that you want to send in for them.